# how can i fix this error (ErrorException Trying to get property 'warehouse' of non-object)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

> ErrorException Trying to get property 'warehouse' of non-object (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory\resources\views\partials\contentheader.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory\resources\views\partials\contentheader.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory\resources\views\partials\contentheader.blade.php)

Comment: please provide some of your code

Comment: please see http://prntscr.com/knbdok  and http://prntscr.com/knbdz3

Comment: This is a very common error and the error message is explicit. You are trying to get the property "warehouse" of a non-object. You must have a `$something->warehouse` in your code where `$something` is null.

Comment: could you dump \Auth::user ? And show us what do relation have ? as @MarcBellêtre mentioned relation might be null or array. You can use `dd()` method for dumping your vars in laravel

Answer (score 0):

You've got 'warehouse' as a property of 'user' and you're trying to use it on the auth'ed user:

```
Auth::user()->warehouse
```

Is the user logged in?

Comment: Enclose it in an if statement? i.e.  @if (Auth::user())